# How to write to a specific line in a text file using vb

Tags: function, vb6, text-files

I have a text file with this sample data

> abduct test|1
>   chip test|2
>   hatter test|3
>   evil test|4

I would like to know how I could loop through it to find a user and remove that line.

This is what I have so far:

```
Public Sub RemoveMember(member As String)
Dim u As String, strdata() As String

Open (App.Path & "\Membership.txt") For input As #1
    Do

    input #1, u

    strdata = Split(u, "|")

    If strdata(0) = member Then
        'figure out a way to remove this line from the text file'
    End If

    Loop Until EOF(1)

Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I would say:

- Read in the lines one by one
- Check if the line contains the member to be deleted
- Write back the line to a new file if it does not
- After reading all the lines delete the original file
- Rename the new file to the original file

Stefan's method is probably faster but will use a lot of memory if the file grows very large.

I am not familiar wityh VB's native file method. Using FileSystemObject (reference Microsoft Scripting Host) you wil get:

```
Dim clsOriginalFile as TextStream
Dim clsNewFile as TextStream
Dim FSO as New FileSystemObject
Dim varLine as Variant
Dim strLine as String

set clsOriginalFile=FSO.OpenTextFile "members.txt", ForReading
set clsNewFile =FSO.OpentTextFile "temp.txt", ForWriting, True

Do While Not clsOriginalFile.AtEndOfStream
    varLine = clsOriginalFile.ReadLine
    strLine=varLine
    If instr(strLine,member)=0 Then
        clsNewFile.WriteLine strLine
    End If
Loop

clsOriginalFile.Close
clsNewFile.Close

FSO.DeleteFile("members.txt")
FSO.MoveFile("temp.txt","members.txt")
```

Written without the help of the IDE, so there may a few typos in the code.